# How do I make the image in the MySQL table alter based on the id

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I have a table with an "id" that automatically increment each time a new entry is added to the table. In the same table, I also store images.

Regardless of the id incrementing the image is always the same.

I would like the images to change based on the "id". How do I achieve this?
Find below my code to file: displayImage.php:

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

// select our database
mysql_select_db("flightSched") or die(mysql_error());

// get the image from the db
$sql = "SELECT image FROM flightSched";

// the result of the query
$result = mysql_query("$sql") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());

// set the header for the image
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo mysql_result($result,1);

// close the db link
mysql_close($link);
```

And the code with the incrementing "id"

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, flightNo, airline, origin, arrivalTime, status 
                       FROM flightSched ") 
    or die(mysql_error());  

    $variable= 'id=basicBoard';
    //echo $variable;


    echo "<table border='1' id='customers'>";
    echo "<tr> <th></th> <th>Flight No</th> <th>Airline</th> <th>Origin</th> <th>Arrival</th> <th>Status</th> ";
    // keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
        // Print out the contents of each row into a table
        echo "<tr " . $variable . "><td>"; 

        echo '<img src="displayImage.php?id=' . $row['id'] . ' " width="40" height="40" >';
        echo "</td><td>"; 
        echo $row['flightNo'];
        echo "</td><td>"; 
        echo $row['airline'];
        echo "</td><td>"; 
        echo $row['origin'] . $row['id'];
        echo "</td><td>"; 
        echo $row['arrivalTime'];
        echo "</td><td>"; 
        echo $row['status'];
        echo "</td></tr>"; 

        if ($variable == 'id=basicBoard')
            {
            $variable = 'class=alt';
            //echo $variable;
            } 
        elseif ($variable == 'class=alt')
            {
            $variable = 'id=basicBoard';
            //echo $variable;
            } 
        } 

        echo "</table> <br/> <br/>";
```

Looking forward to your reply.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't used the ID to limit the results in your displayImage.php file.

Change

```
$sql = "SELECT image FROM flightSched";
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT image FROM flightSched WHERE id = '$_GET[id]'";
```

This will get it working but is an example, but please sanitize the GET value instead of just using it directly in the sql.

Comment: Your solution would have been brilliant if I fed in a "id" through a form, but I don't. The limitations are put via the Query.

Comment: In your image src you do `displayImage.php?id=' . $row['id'] . ' "` which is adding `?id=` to the displayImage php file, this can be accessed using `$_GET['id']` inside displayImage.php

Comment: Great it works... Thank you SO much for making it so clear to me.